# Add vertical space inside \underset

Tags: spacing, align, vertical-alignment, subscripts

I have this code:

```
    \begin{equation*}
\underset{\z \in \mathbb{R}^n}{\min}\ \underset{\y \in \mathbf{B}^{n-1}_{\infty}}{\max} \  \left\{\frac{1}{2} \right\}  .
\end{equation*}
```

This results into following:

[image]

As you can see, the expressions under `\min` and `\max` are not aligned properly and does not look good. Any help regarding fixing will be great!

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You shouldn't be using `\underset` to begin with, but `\min_{...}` and `\max_{...}`.

With `mathtools` (that also loads `amsmath`) you can use `\adjustlimits`:

```
\documentclass{article}
\usepackage{mathtools}
\usepackage{amssymb}
\usepackage{bm}

\newcommand{\y}{\bm{y}}
\newcommand{\z}{\bm{z}}

\begin{document}

\begin{equation*}
\adjustlimits
  \min_{\z \in \mathbb{R}^n}
  \max_{\y \in \mathbf{B}^{n-1}_{\infty}}
  \left\{\frac{1}{2}\right\}.
\end{equation*}

\end{document}
```

[image]

For more than two operators you can look at https://tex.stackexchange.com/a/409671/4427

Comment: Awesome solution! Thanks a lot, sir!