How to change the size of the text under min and arg min commands?
We are looking at the following MWE:
\documentclass{article}

\usepackage{optidef}
\DeclareMathOperator*{\argminA}{arg\,min}

\begin{document}

    $$n\in\argminA_{j\in\{C, D\}}{\min_{v\in \{A, B\}} w(j,v)}$$

\end{document}

This produces the following:

How can I achieve that the fontsize below the second min is the same as below the arg min?

It is the same!

Oh maybe only because it is higher then the other one. In this case how can I achieve that they are on the same height? Sorry for this! It looked somehow smaller ...

The only problem is the vertical alignment of the subscripts that can be achieved with mathtools. By the way, optidef has nothing to do with this other than it loads amsmath.
This works for two consecutive operators; for more, you can look at https://tex.stackexchange.com/a/409671/4427
\documentclass{article}
\usepackage{mathtools}

\DeclareMathOperator*{\argminA}{arg\,min}

\begin{document}

\[
n\in\adjustlimits\argminA_{j\in\{C, D\}}\min_{v\in \{A, B\}} w(j,v)
\]

\end{document}

Don't use $$ in a LaTeX document; there's no reason to. See Why is \[ ... \] preferable to $$ ... $$?

